# your completion of the program or the completion of your program

Tags: sentence-structure

I am going to make up a sentence.

(ex) The advanced certificate is given to recognize **the completion of my accounting program** or **my completion of the program.**

Which phrase in bold is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think both are correct. It's just two ways to say the same thing.

Comment: "Completion of my program" is usual and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences are grammatical but not quite idiomatic. Normally the idea is expressed without "my". In any case, the certificate **is** not awarded to recognize *your* completion of the program. It **is awarded** to *those* who complete the program.  It *was* awarded to you to recognize your completion of the program.  Present tense **is awarded** refers to the general case or circumstance.

> The certificate is awarded to students **upon (their) completion** of the program.
>
> I received the certificate **upon (my) completing** the program.

You could say:

> I received the certificate upon my completing the program.

but  *my* is not necessary and is not usual, although it is grammatical.

What is the nuanced difference between **upon completion** and **upon completing**?

**is awarded ... upon completion** states that completion of the program is the requirement for the certificate *at all times*, whereas **I received it upon completing** refers to the act of completion *as it happened, in time*.

So, if you are going to refer an actual awarding of the certificate, the certificate you received when you completed the program, **upon completing** would be the better choice because **-ing** has a temporal meaning which allows it to be a better partner to the tense of **received**:

> I *received* the certificate *upon completing* the program.

But if you are going to refer to the *object of recognition*, then the true noun **completion** would be the better choice, for in that case we are speaking in generalities not of specific actual instances of individuals completing the program.

> The certificate  is awarded to recognize completion of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on how formal your sentence needs to be

> **my completion** of the program
>   The advanced certificate was awarded in recognition of *(my)* completion of the program.

is usually a better choice since the emphasis is that you *completed* the program.

> completion of **my program**
>   "An advanced certificate will be awarded upon completion of *my* program" the instructor told his class.

may be understood to be the program was *given*/*taught* by you without additional context.

> I will be awarded an advanced certificate upon completion of *my program*.

is easily understood if you are talking to friends or people who know you.